# "Not currently on any branch" after doing a commit

Tags: git, branch, commit

I did a checkout to an earlier commit:

```
git checkout 12345
```

Then back to the last commit:

```
git checkout 56789
```

And then continued committing and I'm:

> Not currently on any branch.

Perhaps, I should've done:

```
git checkout master
```

After the first checkout, instead of pointing to a commit id.

Still, any idea how to get my latest commits into the master branch (which is a few commits behind)?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do `git checkout 12345` you will be in no branch state. Do not do that. This is meant for commit inspection rather than working in it.

If you are on master and want to reset your master to the commit that you wanted, use `git reset 12345` ( or supply `--hard` ) If you wanted to branch, use `git checkout -b <name> <sha1>` to create a branch at that point and start working there.

Similarly while coming back, like you mentioned, you should have done `git checkout master`

Now that you have committed over 56789, note down the commit over 56789, and then checkout master, and do:

```
git reset <commit_over_56789>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, your master branch is behind your most recent commit (56789), and you'd like to make it point to that.

If that's the case, doing:

```
git branch -f master 56789
```

will reset the master branch to point to that commit. `git checkout master` after that, and you should be good to go.

Comment: One can also simply `git checkout master && git rebase 56789`, assuming the working copy is clean.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot, Mat and Romain!

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked for me. I personally find this answer more useful than the other one.